# About kubernetes. How can I Cooperative between containers?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to send a command from a container to another container.
Is it possible with SSH?
If you have another method, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need SSH. The kubernetes API can be used to execute commands in other containers (and stream input/output).

If you are not into go you can use the `kubectl exec` command from your container that needs to execute a command in another one.

For both solutions you will need a properly setup ServiceAccount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kubectl exec` to run commands in a container.

If you want to run the shell in a container you can use the command `kubectl exec -it XXX -- /bin/bash` [ref](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/#:%7E:text=Get%20a%20shell%20to%20the%20running%20Container%3A). Then you can run a command like `ping 8.8.8.8` i-e- to check the container connectivity.

To execute a command directly you can use `kubectl exec -it XXX -- /bin/bash -c "command(s)"` instead, [reference](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/anthos/docs/troubleshooting/executing-shell-commands).